# How to get the name of user through relations in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to implement simple teaming option to my app. I have theese tables:

```
users/teams    /team_members/
-----/---------/------------/
id   /id       /id          /
name /user_id  /user_id     /
...  /...      /team_id     /
```

I have 3 models where I have defined relations:

User model:

```
public function teams() {
    return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
}

public function teamMembers() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class, TeamMembers::class);
}
```

Team model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function members() {
    return $this->hasMany(TeamMember::class);
}
```

TeamMember model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

User can only create one team, but join many teams. The problem I have is with displaying data in the frontend.

This is the query I make in the controller:

```
public function index(User $user) {
    $teams = Team::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id )->with('members')->get();
    return view('teams.index')->with('teams', $teams);
}
```

I have a table with the members of the current autheticated user team. I want to display the names if each member but the only thing i can do is $team->member->id and I get the ids of the users but I want to get their names too. I can do it with simple query but I dont want to make new query for every row.

This is the blade file:

```
@if ( $teams->count() > 0 )

                    @foreach ($teams as $team)

                    <table class="table table-striped table-sm table-responsive-lg">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Members</th>
                            <th scope="col">Created</th>
                            <th scope="col" colspan="2"></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$team->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $team->members->count('members')}} {{ Str::plural('member', $team->id) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $team->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="" method="POST">
                                            @method('DELETE')
                                            @csrf
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <br>

                    <h5>Team members:</h5> 

                    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Added</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @foreach ($team->members as $member)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $member->user->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $member->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    @endforeach


                @else
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2>You do not own a team</h2>
                    <p class="lead text-muted">You can create your own team or join the team of other user.</p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createTeamModal">Create team</a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#joinTeamModal">Join team</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                @endif
```

When I changed $team->member->id with $member->user->name it worked. It shows the names of the users but I get N+1 queries alert and I don't know how to fix it (i tried different queries and relations but it didnt work):

[image: n+1 error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `user` relationship from each member. So lets eager load that relationship as well.

```
public function index(User $user) 
{
    $teams = Team::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id )->with('members.user')->get();
    return view('teams.index')->with('teams', $teams);
}
```

Comment: I still recieve the N+1 alert :(

Comment: @Tolga20 My bad! I have updated my answer, pls retry.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I am new to Laravel and I am still struggling with database relationships. Thanks again!!! :)